# How I can prevent every key being sent to KeyboardUpFunc in GLUT?

Tags: c++, keyboard, glut

I'm fairly new to OpenGL, and I am writing a simple game in 2D, for fun. However, I ran into an issue I am having a hard time wrapping my head around.

It seems that whenever my keyboardUpFunc is called, that not only the key that has actually come up sent to the function, but every single key currently being pressed as well.

I'm using a simple key buffer to manage the keys, keyUp marks the key as up and is only called in this function. keyDown is called in my keyboardFunc. isDown returns a boolean value of whether or not the key is pressed. Take this code for example:

```
#include <iostream>
...

void keyboardUp(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    keys.keyUp(key);
    if (keys.isDown('s') == false)
    {
        std::cout << "It's resetting s as well!" << std::endl;
    }
    // reset acceleration here, for each key
    if ( (key == 'w') || (key == 's') )
    {
        yStep = 0.1;
    }
    if ( (key == 'a') || (key == 'd') )
    {
        xStep = 0.1;
    }

    std::cout << key << " is now up." << std::endl;
}
```

If you run this code, if you for example, hold S and D, then release the D key, you will note that S has been marked as up too, since this is the only location keyUp is being called.

Assuming my keyBuffer code is working correctly (and it is, but let me know if you want me to post it...), is there any way to get around this? Where if you were holding a key, and then pressed another key, the application would go back to what you were doing when you were just holding the original key? Instead of marking both as up? Or is this not feasible with GLUT?

Comment: With SDL you can use [`SDL_GetKeyState()`](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_GetKeyState) - I'm not familiar with any GLUT equivalent of that though.

Comment: I was considering just switching to SDL, but hopefully someone knows if this is possible in GLUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my implementation of the keyboard buffer, and what I was describing above now works. The difference is that before I was using a vector to pile on the keys that were being pressed, whereas now, I am using a fixed-size array of boolean values.

Apparently, a vector implementation of a key buffer won't work properly with GLUT.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what is going wrong.. But where/how exactly are you calling this function ?? Directly in the Main Game loop, or are you checking certain conditions in an 'update' function. I ask because you need to check for input every run of the infinite loop, and if you are using a boolean to determine if a key is down, you should essentially reset it after its corresponding action has been performed. Anyway, just my 2 cents.

Comment: It's an 'update' function, glutKeyboardUpFunc to be specific. And keyUp is resetting the boolean...
The problem is that if you are holding say a key to move right and a key to move up at the same time, when you release either of these keys, both are registered as coming up, yet I only stopped pressing one of them.